# Devhelp problem in Ubuntu - MISSING XINCLUDE CONTENT

Tags: gnome, gtk3

After installing `gnome-platform-development`, the Devhelp application  was also installed.

Withon Devhelp, at the code examples sections, there appears a message:

```
MISSING XINCLUDE CONTENT
```

where there should be code examples.

What package(s) must be installed to fix this problem?

[image: Scrennshot]

Answer (score 1):

These steps solve my same problem.

1. Download latest tar.gz archive file that have documentation of GTK+, from GTK+ 3 Reference Manual [download link](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/)
   Now the latest is: gtk3-html-3.24.13.tar.gz
   Then extract it.

   `tar xzvf gtk3-html-3.24.13.tar.gz`
2. Remove current version of GTK+ 3 Reference Manual.

   `rm -rf /usr/share/doc/libgtk-3-doc/gtk3/*`
3. Copy latest downloaded directory to correct location.

   `sudo cp -a gtk3-html-3.24.13/* /usr/share/doc/libgtk-3-doc/gtk3/`

Now devhelp show codes.

[image]

[This](https://quanzhuo.github.io/2017/06/26/devhelp/) is source of my answer.

Comment: Glad that you were able to translate that source into instructions that I can use. Thank you.

Comment: @Kevin Bowen  It's not very hard for me to find out what is the instructions. I think source is in Chinese but English parts enough. Now I can use DevHelp documents to create some simple GUI with GTK+ and C. Thanks for your comment and happy 2020.